# Is there an infinite sequence that converges only for a specific x?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a known infinite sequence $\sum_{i=0}^\infty f_i(x)$ that converges only for a specific $x$, and otherwise diverges?

Comment: $f(x_0) = 0$, $f(x) = 1$ otherwise.

Comment: You don't need esoteric functions $f_i$, any power series with radius of convergence 0 will work. For instance $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n! x^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

$f_i (x = n) = \frac{1}{i!}$ and $f_i (x \neq n) = x^2$